# How to process TXT e-mail template with Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, email, thymeleaf, plaintext

I'm trying to send `plain text` email from Spring application with Thymeleaf.

This is my e-mail service:

```
@Override
public void sendPasswordToken(Token token) throws ServiceException {
    Assert.notNull(token);

    try {

        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("url", url(token));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(
                mimeMessage, false, SpringMailConfig.EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ENCODING
        );

        message.setSubject("Token");
        message.setTo(token.getUser().getUsername());

        final String content = this.textTemplateEngine.process("text/token", ctx);
        message.setText(content, false);

        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServiceException("Token has not been sent", e);
    }
}
```

email is sent and delivered into mailbox.

This is my `plain text` email template:

> Token url: ${url}

but in delivered mailbox `url` variable is not replaced with it's value. Why?

When I use `html` classic HTML Thymeleaf syntax, variable is replaced:

```
<span th:text="${url}"></span>
```

**What is proper syntax for e-mail text template?**

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#textual-template-modes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Thymeleaf in plain text mode as well, like in this example:

```
Dear [(${customer.name})],

This is the list of our products:
[# th:each="p : ${products}"]
   - [(${p.name})]. Price: [(${#numbers.formatdecimal(p.price,1,2)})] EUR/kg
[/]
Thanks,
  The Thymeleaf Shop
```

That means you can have a text-file with just this in it:

```
Token url: [(${url})]
```

Take a look at the complete documentation of those features here:

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395

**Edit**

As mentioned in a comment, make sure to use version >= 3.0 of Thymeleaf:

```
<properties>
  <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
  <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: that is a nice addition of version 3, as states the issue. thanks for posting it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used Thymeleaf `starter` dependency package from Spring and it added Thymeleaf in version 2.x. When I removed version 2 and upgraded to version 3 the syntax is working and, as you mentioned, it's recommended way.

Answer (score 3):

Use an HTML template like this and it will procude plain text.

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:inline="text" th:remove="tag">
Token url: [[${url}]]
</html>
```

another way, still using html could be like this

```
<span th:text="Token url:" th:remove="tag"></span><span th:text="${url}" th:remove="tag"></span>
```

What you are looking is to produce `plain text` so thymeleaf will return that for you.

Comment: this is a proper way to do it. I mean a valid way to do it, im not sure if this is the official or not, I know it works.

Comment: Note that when using the [[]] syntax the text will be html-escaped: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining